Detective TV Show
So, I have seen this same episode twice. I have seen it within the last 5 to 7 years. It's a crime show and the lead detective is a female. 
** Not 100% sure ** but it looks like its suppose to take place in Texas or Arizona or some where along those lines. In the episode there are a bunch of kids in some house just partying, when guys come running down the hill from behind the house. They run in and kill almost everyone in the house and make the killings look like they are ritualistic Indian killings. 
The detective goes to the local native american reservation and get help from their lead law enforcer. Turns out the killings were setup to try to make trouble for the reservation. The crime was actually done by a cult or a Caucasian gang. The detectives found out that the next target was a school on the reservation. So they cleared the school and took down the attackers when they showed up. 
One thing that stood out was the native american officer preferred knifes to guns. Last but not least, if I am not mistaken at the end of the episode the detective goes to visit her sister and after she leaves, her sister looks into a bag that she had hidden whose bag had a ton of drugs in it.
Just wanted to thank any and everyone assistance that you may be able to offer.

This is basically the plot of The Tribe from season 1 of Criminal Minds, but the team is not lead by a woman and I don't think there's a sister and a bag of drugs there either. Is it possible you're mixing two shows here?

(In fact, that part sounds more like In Plain Sight, where the female protagonist was a US marshal and IIRC her sister was involved with drugs.)

@Walt Yes sir you are correct on both notes. I watched the Tribe episode and i definitely was getting that mixed up with an episode of In Plain Sight. Thank you very much!

@Walt Now i am fairly new to this site. So i am trying to find out how do i accept your comments on this question as an answer? Or would it have to be posted another way for me to accept as an answer? Thank you for any assistant that can be offered on this as well.  Just to note i only have 6 ratings, im thinking that may be holding me back on this. Not sure tho.

Criminal Minds
Season 1, Episode 16: The Tribe

When college students in New Mexico are found tortured and murdered in an unoccupied house, the BAU suspects a group of killers with an extensive knowledge of Native American rituals is responsible.

More information available on the Criminal Minds wikia or the IMDB page.
